# Can we identify the largest product of two numbers made from four given digits

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My problem is, given 4 positive integers (single digits 0-9), is there a generic way to identify which combination of them will yield the largest product of a single multiplication?

So to clarify if my digits were: `3`, `8`, `1`, `6`

I think the largest number I could make given a single multiplication would be `8` * `631` = 5048

or in generic terms, the largest single digit multiplied by a combination of the rest of the digits in a sequence of decreasing magnitude.

1. is that correct?
2. is there a way to formally state that? Sort of a proof.

Comment: $83\cdot61 = 5063$.

Comment: $81*63 = 5103 > 5048$. I suspect this gives the highest product: the larger two numbers as tens digits, then the smaller two numbers as ones digits, but switched (so the smallest digit goes with the largest digit).

Comment: @MJD - well, I guess that answers #1.

Comment: And $8631$ is larger yet, taking the empty multiplier to be $1$ as is often done.

Comment: @RossMillikan - What is an empty multiplier? Keeping in mind I'm no math major...

Comment: @Mike:  You are splitting the four digits into two sets, and I put all of them in one set.  When you have an empty set as a multiplier, often it is considered $1$ instead of $0$.  It makes many formulas cleaner.  When you are adding it makes sense to consider it $0$, the identity.  As $1$ is the multiplicative identity it corresponds.  One example is $0!$ is an empty product and we set it to $1$

Comment: This feels like the premise of a Project Euler problem lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be obvious that the digits in each number must be decreasing.  It looks like you prohibit $abcd (\times 1)$.  We can sort the digits $a \ge b \ge c \ge d$ - do you allow pairs to match?  First let's look at splitting the digits $3$ and $1$.  We need to compare $a \times bcd, b \times acd, c \times abd, d \times abc$.    Comparing $a \times bcd=100ab+10ac+ad$ with $b \times acd=100ab+10bc+bd$ we see the former is larger because $a \ge b$  A similar argument will show that $a \times bcd$ beats the others.

Similarly we can compare $ac\times bd=100ab+10(ad+bc)+bd$ with $ad \times bc=100ab+10(ac+bd)+cd$.  We would rather have more copies of the big $a$, so the second wins.

Finally we need to compare $a \times bcd=100ab+10ac+ad$ with $ad \times bc=100ab+10(ac+bd)+cd$.  The second is the winner.

Comment: Perfect! I assume we could do this for any number of digits the proof would just get longer as there are more combinations to check?

Comment: @Mike:Yes.  I believe the answer is that you split the number of digits as evenly as possible and put all the big ones behind the second biggest.  So if you have $a,b,c,d,e,f$ in that decreasing order you want $aef \times bcd$

Comment: @RossMillikan It seems to me you want to alternate, so you would have $ade \times bcf$ in the case of siz digits. For example, if you have 1-6, yours gives $621\times543 = 337203$, while mine gives $632\times541 =341912$.

Comment: @JonathanChristensen:  you are right, you want the third and fourth largest in the tens place.  But you want the larger of each pair behind the smaller leading digit.  Here $631 \times 542=342002$  This lets you multiply the $2$ by a larger number.

Answer (score 1):

We have digits

$a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i \in S=\left\{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 \right\}$,

$a \geq b \geq c \geq d \geq e \geq f \geq g \geq h \geq i$,

and we want to find out the maximum possible product of two numbers, constructed by digits from the set $S$, by each time having one more extra digit starting from two digits to use option, then we would have the following

for the case $a>b$ we have:

$a \cdot b=max$,

$a \cdot \overline{bc}=max$,

$\overline{ad} \cdot \overline{bc}=max$,

$\overline{ad} \cdot \overline{bce}=max$,

$\overline{adf} \cdot \overline{bce}=max$,

$\overline{adf} \cdot \overline{bceg}=max$,

$\overline{adfh} \cdot \overline{bceg}=max$,

$\overline{adfh} \cdot \overline{bcegi}=max$.

With line over the number meaning $\overline{bce}=b\cdot 10^2+c\cdot 10+e$, representing three digit number with digits $b, c$ and $e$ respectively, which is different from $bce=b\cdot c\cdot e$ etc.

There is a clear pattern there. Each time adding a new digit in a zik-zak order to one of the factors, starting from "$b$" in three digit option, as its new last digit.

In case $a=b$ we ignore $a$ and $b$ for a moment, do the same procedure as above with rest of the optional digits and then just add $a=b$ as first digit to each of the factors.

This can be done with any number of digits from the set $S$.
There will be some equal digits when you have more then nine of them to use but the zik-zak method from above is the same to get the maximum product.

To make sure those are the maximum products you could check $2^{n-1}-1$ possible potential maximum products for $n$ optional digits from the set $S$. I did that for the case of $n=5, 6, 7$, and wanted to do it for the $n=8, 9$ also, but there is so much work to do there and you get lost easily. You could probably use *Mathematica* or some other program to do the calculation but I haven't done that. So I searched for another shorter approach and seem to find it.

This can be better understood if you put both factors one over the other and then multiply them in a "criss-cross" method known from vedic math, also known as "vertically and cross-wise" method, which is not thought in school usually.

There is this same problem mentioned in the book "Ingenious Mathematical Problems and Methods" by L. A. Graham, for the nine digit option case, page $5$ and solution at $63$. There is a few direction points for explanation there and the case with construction of two factors one over the other which could be connected with the "criss-cross" method.

Answer (score 1):

The following algorithm will yield two numbers with the maximum product for any number of given digits, possibly with repetitions.

1. Start with two "numbers" $x, y$ with no digits.
2. Go through all given digits in descending order one at a time. For each digit add it to the smaller of numbers $x, y$. A number with no digits has value $0$. If $x=y$ add the digit to any one of them.

Examples:

$4, 3, 2, 1\;\;\;ad \times bc\;\;\;41 \times 32 = 1312$

$5, 4, 3, 2, 1\;\;\;ad \times bce\;\;\;52 \times 431 = 22412$

$4, 4, 3, 2, 1\;\;\;ac \times bde\;\;\;43 \times 421 = 18103$

Notice different alternation patterns between the last two examples.